# Why React callback bind to null works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A working WebpackBin can be found at link below,

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kibrw5tNNrsQpENUv_M

I have two components. Parent component pass a function to its child component via prop and child component's event handler invoke the passed in function via `func.bind(null, num)` to provide extra pre-set argument.

Why `dummyFunc.bind(null, 666)` works, should not `bind` make the newly created function `this` context become `null`? Hence, every `this.setState` should become undefined.

---

Parent Component Code,

```
import React from 'react'
import Component from './Component'

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      foo: 2
    }

    this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)
  }

  foo(newValue) {
    this.setState({
      foo: newValue + this.state.foo
    })
    console.log(this.state.foo)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <Component dummyFunc={this.foo} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Child Component Code,

```
import React from 'react'

const Component = ({dummyFunc}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={dummyFunc.bind(null, 666)}>BUTTON</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Component
```

Comment: Your 666 is very 666, so I give you a double-click 666!

Comment: `this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)` clearly binds it to some other context already

Comment: will it be re-bound by doing `dummyFunc.bind(null)`?

Comment: No, obviously not, as then the code would not work.

Comment: Thanks that solved my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why alert.bind(null, 666) works, should not bind make the newly created function this context become null?

It only changes the context of the function you're binding to: `alert` (and only for the newly created bound function). So inside the `alert` function the context would be changed, which is almost fine - since internally `alert` would not use the default context, but that's not constrained.

The purpose of that code is to partially apply the argument for the `alert` function - that is a number `666`.

From that perspective it would be more semantically correct to use anonymous functions:

```
<button onClick={() => alert(666)}>BUTTON</button>
```

In your bin you:

```
this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)
```

So you have bound a context explicitly. After you do that every other `.bind()` does not change the context anymore (it is as per the standard).

Comment: I do understand your code sample at the end and that do make sense for me. However, the first part is not quite clear to me. I updated my question (see code block at the end of question).

Comment: @LiXinyang No, it should not be equivalent: browser's `alert` function has no connection with react and its `setState` at all. It's a function that shows a popup message, nothing more.

Comment: I should never use `alert` as a function placeholder. Please see my update

Comment: @LiXinyang see the answer update.